# fuelphp : correct way to create login portal (MVC)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, fuelphp

I'm creating simple login portal using fuelphp framework. what is the correct way to create login portal in fuelphp framework.

what is the correct **controller** following dir,

[image]

and also what is the **model** and **view** for ?

can anyone explain to me ? I'm confusing at this point. currently I'm creating,

> controller : fuel/app/classes/controller
>
> model : fuel/app/classes/model
>
> view : fuel/app/views

is this correct ? fuelphp framework has many controller,model,views that's why i asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to read up on the basics of MVC, of which there is plenty of information out there on google.

The basics are that a URL routes to a `controller`, the `controller` can then use a `model` to load or manipulate data, which is then passed to the `view` to be displayed to the user.

The file paths you listed are correct, you want to be working within the `fuel/app` folder.

The [FuelPHP MVC documentation](http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/mvc.html) has a basic outline of each part along with links to more information and how to utilise that using the framework.

Answer (score 0):

On basics if you are coding, use the controller and model under the "app/classes" folder. Also use the views under the "app" folder.